# Question on regex from course using python to interact with operating system on coursera

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

> Fill in the code to check if the text passed includes a possible U.S. zip code, formatted as follows: exactly 5 digits, and sometimes, but not always, followed by a dash with 4 more digits. The zip code needs to be preceded by at least one space, and cannot be at the start of the text.

```
import re

def check_zip_code (text):
    result = re.search(r"___", text)
    return result != None
print(check_zip_code("The zip codes for New York are 10001 thru 11104.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("90210 is a TV show")) # False
print(check_zip_code("Their address is: 123 Main Street, Anytown, AZ 85258-0001.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("The Parliament of Canada is at 111 Wellington St, Ottawa, ON K1A0A9.")) # False
```

Replace the dash `____` with the answer. Here is mine `"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"`
This solution is absolutely right and works fine. Anyone find an alternate solution for this problem because I don't think so. Writing `[0-9]` this so many time there might be a better solution.

Comment: Exactly the same question and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check_zip_code(text):
    return re.search(r'\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?', text) != None
```

I use exactly 5 digits (`{n}`) followed by an non-capturing group (`(?: ..)`) which is optional due to the question mark.